# Deleting from a database Laravel9

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I am trying to delete from a database in Laravel 9, My code in the blade php file is:

```
<form action="/waifus/{{ $waifu->id }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <button class="text-red-500"> Delete</button>
</form>
```

My code in the web php file is:

```
// Delete Waifu
Route::delete('/waifus/{waifu}', [WaifuController::class, 'delete']);
```

My code in the WaifuController is:

```
 //Delete waifu
    public function delete(Waifu $waifu)
    {
        dd($waifu);
        $waifu->delete();
        return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Waifu deleted succesfully');
    }
```

The problem I am facing is that, when ever I click the button inside the form, it only reloads the same page with the url:
"http://localhost:8000/waifus/7?search=&_token=uE61kaZBtkCkZ4oVW8cacld3sbXaWxaJzLRixQ6X&_method=DELETE"
And it doesn't go to the die dump method in the controller, any help is apricated.

Edit:
Adding a new empty form like this solved my problem, but I still don't know why, can someone please explain it.

```
    <form>
    Delete: 
    </form>

    <form action="/waifus/{{ $waifu->id }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <button class="text-red-500"> Delete</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Looks like you have a form within another form, which is not permitted in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have nested form elements. Place your form outside the main form with a button inside that submits the delete form.

```
<button type="submit" form="delete_waifu" class="text-red-500"> Delete</button>
```

then outside of the main form

```
<form id="delete_waifu" action="/waifus/{{ $waifu->id }}" method="POST">
  @csrf @method('DELETE')
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="/waifus/{{ $waifu->id }}" method="POST">
@csrf
@method('DELETE')
<button type="submit" class="text-red-500"> Delete</button>
</form>

//Delete
public function delete($waifu)
{   
  Model::find($waifu)->delete(); // Model name will be your Model name
  return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Waifu deleted succesfully');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add button type submit like;

```
<button type="submit" class="text-red-500"> Delete</button>
```

Comment: buttons with no type are assumed to be "submit"

Answer (score -1):

in your controller

```
 //Delete waifu
public function delete($waifu)
{
    $waifu = Waifu::find($waifu)->delete(); //supposed Waifu is your Model
    return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Waifu deleted succesfully');
}
```